# I'm performing calculations in Excel and getting '#VALUE! error because one of the cells is text

Tags: excel

[image: value picture]

I'm performing calculations in Excel and getting '#VALUE! error (see value pictures above) because one of the cells is text, specifically, N/A, which is a legitimate field entry.

How can I convert the N/A to a 0 for the purpose of the calculation without actually changing the N/A that people see?

I don't want to throw a 0 for the whole result using IFERROR - I want it to calculate if it were a 0.  I have this for a typical row...

```
=LET(total,SUMIF(AD21:AI21,"N/A",$AD$729:$AI$729)+SUMIF(AD21:AI21,"",$AD$729:$AI$729),
    count,COUNTIFS(AD21:AI21,">=1",AD21:AI21,"<=5"),
    (((((((AD$729+total/count)*AD21)+
    (AE$729+total/count)*AE21)+
    (AF$729+total/count)*AF21)+
    (AG$729+total/count)*AG21))+
    (AH$729+total/count)*AH21)+
    (AI$729+total/count)*AI21)
```

Comment: Surround each calculation with iferror() like so: iferror((AE$729+total/count)*AE21),0)

Comment: `SUM((AD$729:AI$729+total/count)*AD21:AI21)`  No need to do each separately.

Comment: Having this 
 =LET(total,SUMIF(AD2:AI2,"N/A",$AD$729:$AI$729)+SUMIF(AD2:AI2,"",$AD$729:$AI$729),count,COUNTIFS(AD2:AI2,">=1",AD2:AI2,"<=5"),SUM((AD$729:AI$729+total/count)*AD2:AI2))                                                          how do I not perform the sum function at the end for a cell that has N/A in it but perform it for all the others?

Comment: surround each calculation with iferror()

Comment: these solutions are helping me return a 0 if there is an error, but I don't want that - I want the calculations to return a number by making the N/A a 0 for the purpose of calculations, not simply putting a 0 in the final cell AK if there is an error thanks